# error while connecting to oracle db using oracle client. I am able to connect using ODBC data source administrator. But not in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, database-connection, oracleclient

I am able to connect to oracle db using ODBC data source administrator using below method and connection is succesful.

[image]
[image]

But if I try to connect using Excel vba using below connection string. I am getting error.

```
   strConnection1 = "DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit};DBQ=dw-server.int:1521/pdw1s_default;UID=user;PWD=pass"
   adoConnection.Open strConnection1
```

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

I tried different combinations for Driver like `Microsoft ODBC for Oracle'. But still same error. PATH is set Oracle client in environment variables. I don't know what I am missing. Please help

Comment: Which folder is defined in PATH? According to your screenshot you have (at least) two Oracle Clients installed. They may clash with each other.

Comment: Is your Excel 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Excel is 64-bit and path is set correctly for `Oracle in OraClient12Home1_32bit.` C:\app\client\ze087788\product\12.2.0\client_1\bin

Comment: @RobertBaron, it is the opposite, `C:\Windows\sysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` launches the **32-bit** ODBC Administrator.

Comment: When your Excel is 64-bit then you have to install the 64-bit Oracle Client/ODBC driver. Apparently you have the 32-bit version installed. In case you like to install both 32-bit and 64-bit, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Comment: Thanks a lot for the details!  I will follow the instruction specified.